# ajax post not working on ajax get from inside div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am working on a customer management system and im currently stuck on an issue i have been trying to work out for a week and have now run out of ideas

i have index.php basically its a simple form you submit a customers first name and last name then ajax sends the request to functions2.php to add to a database then reports back success or not then webapp_get_customers retrieves and updated table with the new customer into the webapp_get_customers div without refreshing the page this is working perfectly

however on the get.php page i have a table that selects results from a table then adds the same form below to be able to edit the customers name when i edit on the index page its opening the form correctly in a modal but is not not submitting the form like it cannot find the ajax

so what i am chasing is how can i get it to look into the webapp_get_customers div to see if a form is submitted or am i going about this all wrong. im thinking the browser cannot see the code inside the div that resides on the get.php page its just returning the loaded content

please help its very much apreciated

```
<form  name='frm_details' class='frm_details' id='frm_details0' action=''>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_fname' required>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_lname' required>   
<input type='submit' value='Save' > 
</form> 

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('form.frm_details').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',                       
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                      success: function(data) {
                           if(data.status == '1')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            } 
                           if(data.status == '2')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            }                               
                        }  
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
    function webapp_get_customers(){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/limitless/get.php',
       dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function( data ) {
      $('#webapp_get_customers').html(data);
      });
    }   
    webapp_get_customers();
    </script>       


    <div id='webapp_get_customers'></div>
```

Comment: You are not passing any values on get.php?

Comment: at the current stage get.php just displays the whole table theres only 6 customers in there and it repeats and edit modal for each row

Comment: @Nathan, is your function webapp_get_customers being called ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove send jquery ajax function from the function, and call it in this way :

```
<form  name='frm_details' class='frm_details' id='frm_details0' action=''>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_fname' required>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='cu_lname' required>   
    <input type='submit' value='Save' > 
    </form> 

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('form.frm_details').on('submit', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',                       
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                          success: function(data) {
                               if(data.status == '1')
                                {
                                    $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                                } 
                               if(data.status == '2')
                                {
                                    $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                                }                               
                            }  
                    });
                });
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: '/limitless/get.php',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                     //alert(html);
                     $('#webapp_get_customers').html(data);
                  }
                });

            });
        </script>    

        <div id='webapp_get_customers'></div>
```

Comment: once question i have is when the form is submitted how can i get it to regrab get.php to update the page with the data just submitted

Comment: so on page load the will load the ajax get and listen for submitions of the forms however once a form has been submitted its not regrabbing a copy of the database with the details just submitted

Comment: @Nathan, are you trying to say that the the data is not inserting in the db, or you are trying to say that the results are not changing there ? Sorry but I'm not able to understand the English that you are writing.

Comment: im trying to say that the results are not changing there until the page is refreshed

Comment: ok, after your second ajax, **just add this line in success function of second ajax**, after this line : `$('#webapp_get_customers').html(data); location.reload(); `

Comment: just cleared the browser cache and now this solution is not allowing anything inside the div to be submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97505/discussion-between-nehal-and-nathan).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend u to use AjaxSubmit to submit a form, it will handle serialization of form fields for you.

```
$("#yourFormSelector").ajaxSubmit({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   beforeSend: function (msg) {
       //Do something before sending your request
   },
   success: function (data, status, xhr) {
       //Do something on success
   },
   error: function (xhr, status, error) {
       //Do something on success
   },
   complete: function (event, xhr, option) {
       //Do something on complete (whether it was successful or not)
   } 
});
```

Comment: any chance on getting an example

Comment: @Nathan i provided an example for your, just use ajaxSubmit on your form selector like this.

Comment: im gonna give this a go

Comment: @Nathan good, give it a shot btw don't forget to download and import it's library. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download

Comment: gave this ago was a bit more involved then i would have liked but thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want check the submit process, you can open develop tools in chrome (or Firefox), click the network panel. All the requests showing there. Second, if you add a form (or other DOM) after the page loaded, the event listener will not be added to it correctly. You need to manually bind it again.

Comment: any chance you could show some code how to bind again

Comment: can you print some error for me ? from your develop tools console

Comment: the console doesn't show any errors. doesn't show any when i submit the form inside the div either

Comment: Does any network request send out ? when you click the button?

Comment: when i click the first submit on the index page but none from inside the div

Comment: If you try to add a new form to a  loaded page , you can  use delegation  to  handle all forms submit event. For example [Delegation](http://jsfiddle.net/founddrama/ggMUn/)

Comment: Käsebrot's method was more the method i was chasing but thanks for your help